# Is Commons Components HttpClient IdleConnectionMonitorThread needed?

Tags: apache-httpclient-4.x

The Commons HTTP client docs [provide an implementation](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html) of `IdleConnectionMonitorThread` that periodically closes old connections. It states

> The only feasible solution that does not involve a one thread per socket model for idle connections is a dedicated monitor thread used to evict connections that are considered expired due to a long period of inactivity

Internally, `PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.closeExpiredConnections()` calls `entry.isExpired()`. This is the [same call](https://github.com/apache/httpcomponents-core/blob/670d5500128ab7fed2e66efa2a9a8e9d6834a61a/httpcore/src/main/java/org/apache/http/pool/AbstractConnPool.java#L333-L335) that's made when acquiring a connection from the pool.

Other than latency in requesting connections, why is `IdleConnectionMonitorThread` recommended if both implementations of `HttpClientConnectionManager` (`PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager` and `BasicHttpClientConnectionManager`) have logic for closing old connections?

Answer (score 0):

There is enough reasons to avoid build-up of state connections in half-closed state.

Usually one needs evict idle / expired connections from a separate monitor thread only if the system tends to have very long periods of communication inactivity. Having said that I personally see no good reason to not have a low priority monitor thread that cleans up the connection pool every other minute or so.

Comment: > long periods of communication inactivity. Good point. As for a reason not to, added code and complexity.